# how to define condition with clicked objet's parent?

Tags: jquery, click, parent

i cant access clicked object(this) parent's class..
click same elements and different returns?

[this is DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Aw39W/10/)

HTML

```
<div class="rows row1">
  <div class="ele">1</div>
  <div class="ele">1</div>
  <div class="ele">1</div>
</div>

<div class="rows row2">
  <div class="ele">2</div>
  <div class="ele">2</div>
  <div class="ele">2</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.ele').click(function() {

  if ( $(this).parent().hasClass('r1') ) {//way1
    alert('you clicked 1st row element');
  }

  else if ( $(this).parent().hasClass('r2') === true ) {//both way wont work
    alert('you clicked 2nd row element');
  }

});
```

​

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because both parent have no `r1` or `r2` class, that should be `row1` and `row2`:

```
$('.ele').click(function() {

  if ( $(this).parent().hasClass('row1') ) {
    alert('you clicked 1st row element');
  }

  else if ( $(this).parent().hasClass('row2')) {
    alert('you clicked 2nd row element');
  }

});
```

[**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Aw39W/18/)