# How to make a table row unclickable in jquery datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Am using jQuery Datatables for listing of the users, and using the selectable property to select and unselect rows. Now I have a issue that I want to make one row non clickable (i.e. the row of logged in user)... how can I do that ..Any help will be appreciated

```
$('#example tr').click( function() { 

}
```

How can I disable this function for a particular row?

Comment: are you using checkboxes to select rows?

Comment: @Sachyn no row selection property of datatable

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? (add `class="trDisable"` to the row that shall have no click function)

```
$('#example tr').not("#example tr.trDisable").click( function()
```

or

```
$('#example tr.trDisable').click( function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

two ways come to my mind

1 each() usage

```
$('#example tr').each(function(i) {
    if ( i === 2 ) {//this will select third tr
      $(this).off();
    }
});
```

2 eq() usage //im not really sure this works on tables, maybe index() will

```
var disabledRow = $('#example tr').eq(2);//this will deactive third row
if ( contition ) {
  disabledRow.off();
}
```

and you can read these questions, they should help

[jquery disable click until animation is fully complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283341/jquery-disable-click-until-animation-is-fully-complete)

[how to define condition with clicked objet's parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278326/how-to-define-condition-with-clicked-objets-parent)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but might help someone..

```
        $('#example').on('click', 'tbody tr', function () {
            var table = $('#example').DataTable();

            // Check if any rows are selected
            if (table.row(this, { selected: true }).any()) {
                // if condition here, if not valid
                if (!condition) table.row(this).deselect();
            }
        });
```